# How to reference a hash in Perl?

Tags: perl, hash, reference

If i have something like this:

```
%hash = {foo => 'bar', foo1=>'bar1',};
```

or

```
%hash = (foo => 'bar', foo1=>'bar1',);
```

or

```
$hash = {foo => 'bar', foo1=>'bar1',};
```

or

```
$hash = (foo => 'bar', foo1=>'bar1',);
```

How do the above codes differ? and how do i access their components?

Comment: `use strict; use warnings;`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `(...)` sorts out precedence, while `{...}` creates an hash *reference*.

```
%hash = {foo => 'bar', foo1=>'bar1',};
```

Assigns the `%hash` a single value. However, hashes are assigned an even-sized list of key-value-pairs. Your code will use the stringification of the hashref as a key (`HASH(0x123ABC)`), and `undef` as value. Please `use warnings` to tell you when you are assigning a non-even-sized list to a hash variable.

```
%hash = (foo => 'bar', foo1=>'bar1',);
```

is correct. The RHS list is evaluated in list context, and is assigned to the hash variable. You can access entries like `$hash{foo}`.

```
$hash = {foo => 'bar', foo1=>'bar1',};
```

is correct. A hash reference is assigned to a scalar variable. You can access elements like `$hash->{foo}`. Note the *dereferencing arrow* which is neccessary to disambiguate hashref access from hash access (you can have variables named both `%hash` and `$hash` in the same scope).

```
$hash = (foo => 'bar', foo1=>'bar1',);
```

evaluates the list on the RHS in scalar context, and will assign the *last* value. So `$hash = "bar1"` is the same thing.

Comment: I know these are just examples, but remove the last comma inside the brackets, some newbies will try and run this code and end up with errors. :)

Comment: @HarryBarry I understand your concerns, but even with the trailing commata, all examples are syntactically valid and run “correctly”. I did not wish to change the formatting from the question when it wasn't neccessary.

Comment: @HarryBarry, it works. Try it. In fact it looks nice/symmetrical when you write a hash across multiple lines.

Comment: @amon hey man, Can I ask a favor? if you know some website that have all kinds of exercises for Perl can you link me? I want to test my Perl skills. Thanks

Comment: @BelmarkCaday The [perlmaven](http://perlmaven.com/perl-tutorial) site has solid tutorials (work in progress). The [Modern Perl](http://www.onyxneon.com/books/modern_perl/index.html) book is a good way to relearn Perl with modern idioms and best practices. When you see an example, try to solve it on your own before reading on. You can also read old stackoverflow questions and try understanding the problems before looking at the answers. And if stuck, keep asking: you have some great questions here!

Answer (score 3):

1. Assigns a hash reference to a hash. This doesn't make sense.
2. Assigns a list to a hash. This is how you normally handle hashes.
3. Assigns a hash reference to a scalar. This is how you normally handle hash references.
4. Assigns a list to a scalar. You'll end up with the last value being stored.

To assess a scalar value in a hash (2):

```
$hash{'foo'}
```

To access a scalar value in a hashref (3):

```
$hash->{'foo'}
```

See [`perldoc perlref` for more about references](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html)

Answer (score 3):

You want

```
my %hash = ( key1 => 'value1', key2 => 'value2' );  # Hash
```

or

```
my $hash = { key1 => 'value1', key2 => 'value2' };  # Reference to hash
```

---

When one assigns a list to a hash, it is treated as a list of key-value pairs,so the proper way to initialize a hash is

```
my %hash = ( key1 => 'value1', key2 => 'value2' );
```

---

```
{ ... }
```

is similar to

```
do { my %anon = ( ... ); \%anon }
```

It creates an anonymous hash and returns a reference to it. A single reference is not a list of key-value pairs, so the following makes no sense:

```
my %hash = { ... };   # XXX
```

If you did want to store a reference to a hash, you'd store it in a scalar.

```
my $hash = { ... };   # ok
```

---

So what does the following do, then?

```
my $hash = ( a => 'b', c => 'd' );
```

Well,

```
a => 'b', c => 'd'
```

is just a fancy way of writing

```
'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'
```

And since we're assigning to a scalar, the right-hand side of the assignment operator is evaluated in scalar context. A list literal (e.g. `'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'`) in scalar context evaluates in its last item, so

```
my $hash = ( a => 'b', c => 'd' );
```

means

```
my $hash = 'd';
```